# GridView sorting with Generic List in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, datagridview, gridview-sorting

I am doing custom sorting on a gridview that is being bound to a generic list.

My problem is the following:

```
    If direction.ToLower.Contains("desc") Then
        mygv.DataSource = myList.OrderByDescending(Function(w) w.Name)
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending
    Else
        mygv.DataSource = myList.OrderBy(Function(w) w.Name)
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending 
    End If

    mygv.DataBind()
```

How can I replace the field `w.Name` with a parameter given to this function since it might be the name, city, country or any other field?

P.S. in C# using anonymous type it is easy but I am using vb.net here.

Thanks

Comment: PS VB.Net also has anonymous types. However I honestly cannot see how you can do it with them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to do this because you are using Linq to EF or Linq to SQL...

```
Import System.Linq.Expressions

Dim propertyName = "Name"
If direction.ToLower.Contains("desc") Then
    mygv.DataSource = myList.OrderByDescending(PropertyOf(Of Row)(propertyName))
    GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending
Else
    mygv.DataSource = myList.OrderBy(PropertyOf(Of Row)(propertyName))
    GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending 
End If

mygv.DataBind()


Public Function PropertyOf(Of T)(string propertyName) as Expression(Of Func(Of T, object))
    Dim param = Expression.Parameter("x", typeOf T)
    Dim property = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, propertyName);
    Return Expression.Lambda(property, param)
End Function
```

Comment: ...I couldn't tell what your List(Of T) is so I just called it Row...replace the `Row` with your List type. Come to think of it...you didn't say what the type of `myList` is. This is important re: what Linq to use.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in the following event of the gridview:

```
Protected Sub Gridview_Sorting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles Gridview.Sorting
    myList = myList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.GetType().GetProperty(e.SortExpression).GetValue(x)).ToList()
End Sub
```

This should do the job.